# Combinatorial question relating to zero sets of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Then define the Zariski closed set
$$V=\{x\in R^n:f(x)=0\text{ for all }f\in I\}.$$
I'm interested in the quantity
$$p(f)=\frac{|\{x\in V:f(x)=0\}|}{|V|}$$
for various $f\in R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$; that is the proportion of the points in $V$ which are zeros of the polynomial $f$. This ratio always makes sense if $R$ is finite.

Obviously $p(f)=1$ for $f\in I$, but I'm wondering which values $p$ can and can't achieve for $f\notin I$, perhaps making further assumptions about $R$ and $I$. I don't have too much experience in algebra or algebraic geometry so I'd be happy with full answers, references, or just vague suggestions.

Comment: Ideals in polynomial rings are always infinite if they are nontrivial. Indeed, it suffices you note principal ideals are infinite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You're right; it's better to assert that $R$ is finite.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact ideals in polynomial rings are infinite.

Comment: I agree, but for the ratio to be well defined, I only need $V$ to be finite, so it suffices to have $R$ finite.

Comment: The simplest case to try is when $R$ is a finite field and then you should be able to show that the numerator can be any number between zero and $|V|$. Thus, the same will work even if $R$ is a finite product of finite fields.  I am not sure what happens when $R$ has nilpotents. Finally, the set $V$ is seldom called a Zariski closed set by algebraic geometers.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the suggestions. Would one call $V$ a variety or a zero set of something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $R$ is a field. Then $V$ is finite if $R$ is finite or if $I$ is zero-dimensional. In both cases, we can do the following:

Let $V=\{p_1, \dotsc, p_s \}$ and take some polynomials $f_1, \dotsc, f_s$ with $f_i(p_j)=\delta_{ij}$ (You can use Lagrange polynomials to construct the $f_i$).

Then for any subset $\Lambda \subset \{1, \dotsc, s\}$ the polynomial $f=\sum_{i \in \Lambda} f_i$ satisfies

$$f(p_j) = \begin{cases}1, & j \in \Lambda \\ 0, & j \notin \lambda\end{cases},$$

thus we have $$p(f) = \frac{s-|\Lambda|}{|V|}$$

In particular all values $0, \frac{1}{|V|}, \frac{2}{|V|}, \dotsc, \frac{|V|-1}{|V|},1$ can be obtained.